# Using Space Syntax Analysis plugin for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to run the [Space Syntax Analysis](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/spacesyntax/) plugin for QGIS.

I've added the metadata file that was missing, but it does not appear in the Plugin toolbar when I click on it.

Can someone help me to figure out what is going on?